# how to login with hashed password in php to specific website

Tags: php, post

Trying to login to aliexpress.com but i dont know how to do it with hashed password. I dont know about hash encryption or hex encoding. cant find csrf_token either. anyone that can explain to me how to do it? here is what post request is sending...

```
require_once('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl('', true);

$json = $hc->setopt_array(array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://passport.aliexpress.com/newlogin/login.do?appName=aebuyer&fromSite=13',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(
        'loginId' => 'email@gmail.com',
        'password2' => '0e646ace6827a5ae05d92e6773411f7ded66d7d57eb1309c8c39361ebee8f8885eab70ebd9d8152d654ed038148c5b20eec6715d6a6993a163919e5428932707ca0cc5356820c0928dd8b23397e840278b7a4161fe491757e64cfa96781cfbc806104b9d47c717e4a70975728aef82e4bbb9a279f8afbefd2a53e7d8dc675068',
        'keepLogin' => 'false',
        'ua' =>'', '118#ZVWZz/0aGgeraZmXsH24cZZTZeghqHhXZZ4YVHZhzZAzZgZ/VnqVagZuZZzTcHW4ZK4emdaszg2ZZZC/Voq4zeZZuZFhXHWVzeASZzqhZHSXG0W/VoqVqZZzZZuhTHRVZZ2uZYqhzHRZZgCZ0oq4ze2ZZZCTTeRVZZ2uwsqKYh24ZgYGTGbzTgv2Y8ihDOfJz9RCfGqJZV+s2CK9vUnR+neZckrKHKT7fPDV+AG8SMWCugZCmrDtKHZzh7bx2Lu1BZZTtW+LgdhQnd5z4mescJ51oFsuSHxfb4K5xbMq2QBqY1US2Y0FeJnaTv904NSTu02YmJSFAhrwsLWB9iSgEZ8EGKDEGGkloODJEE7w6J1AxK594Lk85SC9UTJUDeIg6J26ulzPFrXjCK28w6nH2HJxWodttHEc8x8wnuf8RQQwofFCjpaJwFsOp8aG5fe1eMaz57jNwjoal0F+WH6qMkvWa8ttw7WHjYuDAVflqVBjDDDGj5WHMCsmqOZTn+w/5pXqQUjhe0OjnUAJl62ltlQEC3bjbkiJnh/7hsRhGkj4f9YPo07/2cFcmDCHjFR8kbfTFFKIaB2617P82/DvWLm0LtT9Ok1/TCLWfeD+v9np4SOjoUpR0qEXmyXZhhZPOvN9MdARI+r/VUHuXKaI+HhJY985e9fKQqf0plDlFW+Is9uP72OVJLMQ1L/c/U36FJdgdN+O7WXFRgLpcBmV+Q5A23QbeykyPNFePGRUcYk0GmESBeGaENNnTBnw0ZdG9F2ELY1c+0eqBLz59QDKEfzJM8lx9wSlh/LJE86RkVY9M6J+0wiDXMktQNsju7e6FTyMVb+pArHO6GsVa5tnn6jmXtKGhprUvZK6oiVD2CBsyOdM+CUc6uLccePcNJrYurgXorm6/qXVJ+hd92Q8hkTn8EtWop5ABwQUujydxFA8akU0BmQNmY2N2Q1bASdOdJ6qrhpmcbB7PpagUoAbqlR0UvIkNsXf9qX/Ou7802DlmwPZv6MHPdmCwS3S2CZ7eS8FN6y0xZdr8HKSV6tZk6RiEfwwekODRlJzdyMVsk3t5j80RP+WQjGFK4/O56c0Dyn4oZek0pseJSzIpIuHd9Z12yi64Ejs+EFXnuY9U06ES+Z+rXKoskepUH==',
        'umidGetStatusVal' => '255',
        'screenPixel'   =>   '1440x900',
        'navlanguage'     => 'en-US',
        'navUserAgent'    => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0',
        'navPlatform'     => 'MacIntel',
        'appEntrance'     => 'aebuyer',
        'appName'         => 'aebuyer',
        'bizParams'       => '',
        'csrf_token'      => 'hP5VhgJTg4eDQudc2d5mp',
        'fromSite'        => '13',
        'hsiz'            =>'FZbYTYGn8rby5yKy_sW2uA',
        'isMobile'         =>'false',
        'lang'             =>'en_US',
        'mobile'          =>'false',
        'returnUrl'       => '',
        'umidToken'       => '48d8d2531d1cefa02ff83f6b01776789984afa84'
    )),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Referer: https://passport.aliexpress.com/mini_login.htm?lang=en_us&appName=aebuyer&appEntrance=default&styleType=auto&bizParams=&notLoadSsoView=false&notKeepLogin=true&isMobile=false&loginId=stefanosn%40gmail.com&cssLink=https://i.alicdn.com/noah-static/4.0.2/common/css/reset-havana.css&cssUrl=https://i.alicdn.com/noah-static/4.0.2/common/css/reset-havana-new-page.css&showMobilePwdLogin=false&defaultCountryCode=GR&ut=&rnd=0.08339089666491883',
        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',

    )
))->exec()->getStdOut();


$parsed = json_decode($json, true);
if ($parsed['success'] !== true) {
    throw new \RuntimeException("Got error from login json: {$json}");
}
else {
  # code...
  echo "we logged in successfully :)";
}
```

I tried with plain password but i get error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Got error from login json: {"content":{"data":{"miniVsts":[],"st":"2wgIvb1NRgCb3kwyLv3EMrA","loginType":"pwdLogin","resultCode":100,"appEntrance":"aebuyer","smartlock":true,"returnUrl":"","stSite":13},"status":0,"success":true},"hasError":false}
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `$parsed['content']['success']` is what you want to check, not `$parsed['success']`.

Comment: Seems like success is true even on error... {"content":{"data":{"titleMsg":"Please enter your password.","resultCode":100},"status":0,"success":true},"hasError":false}

Comment: Then you need to send what the server is expecting. I would imagine the `resultCode` probably tells you whether the login succeeded or not.

Comment: Correct but i dont know how the password hash is created!